# How to open dynamic submenu items inside sub-items with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I made a menu with subitems, as you can see [here - jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5F3c/).

It's working very well. But, on `PRODUTOS` sub-items I need to implement another submenu. This second 'submenu' must be dynamic, because I'll get from the database, who subitems has a submenu, and I have no idea how to implement that on this script.

Any help?

Script:

```
var sPath = window.location.pathname+window.location.search;
var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

$('dd').filter(function () {
   return $('a[href="' + sPage + '"]', $(this)).length == 0
}).hide();

$('dt a.submenu').click(function () {
   $("dd:visible").slideUp("slow");
   $(this).parent().next('dd').slideDown("slow");
   return false;
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
   <dl>
      <dt><a href="#">HOME</a></dt>
      <dt><a href="#" class="submenu">QUEM SOMOS</a></dt>
         <dd>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">EMPRESA</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">INSTITUCIONAL</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">NOSSOS PRODUTOS</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">RESPONSABILIDADE SOCIAL</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">RESPONSABILIDADE AMBIENTAL</a></li>
            </ul>
         </dd>
      <dt><a href="#" class="submenu">PRODUTOS</a></dt>
         <dd>
            <ul class="produtos">

               <li><a href="#">TESTE</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">TESTE</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">TESTE</a></li>
            </ul>
         </dd>
      <dt><a href="#">INFORMATIVO</a></dt>
      <dt class="no_border"><a href="#">CONTATO</a></dt>
   </dl>
</div>
```

Comment: you will have to looking into recursive looping to be able to iterate an infinite level of sub categories

Comment: @hex4 Right, I will pass this to programmer, but on my jQuery, what i need to do? how do I know which item has a submenu, to make my script working?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function of jquery to get your subelements dynamically.
Then you can [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) it to your new lists.

```
<li><a href="#">TESTE</a><ul>here you can append your new items</ul></li>
```

Hope it will help you.